# Multiple sites in Azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My Azure web app (example.azurewebsites.net) has one custom domain, applicationhost.config:

```
<sites>
  <site name="example" id="111111111">
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:customdomain.com" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:customdomain.com" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:example.azurewebsites.net" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:example.azurewebsites.net" />
    </bindings>
    <application path="/" applicationPool="example" preloadEnabled="true">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
      <virtualDirectory path="/iisnodedebugger" physicalPath="C:\DWASFiles\Sites\example\Temp\iisnode" />
    </application>
    <traceFailedRequestsLogging enabled="false" customActionsEnabled="true" directory="D:\home\LogFiles" />
    <detailedErrorLogging enabled="true" directory="D:\home\LogFiles\DetailedErrors" />
    <logFile logSiteId="false" />
  </site>
  ...
</sites>
```

The custom domain's bindigs are automatically added to the default site (example).

I would like to change it, i would like to create a new site with bindings to the custom domain (customdomain.com).

applicationHost.xdt (created with IIS Manager):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.applicationHost>
    <sites>
      <site name="example" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <bindings>
          <binding bindingInformation="*:443:customdomain.com" xdt:Locator="Match(bindingInformation)" xdt:Transform="Remove" />
          <binding bindingInformation="*:80:customdomain.com" xdt:Locator="Match(bindingInformation)" xdt:Transform="Remove" />
        </bindings>
      </site>
      <site name="customdomain" id="222222222" xdt:Transform="InsertAfter(/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site[(@name='example')])">
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:customdomain.com" />
          <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:customdomain.com" />
        </bindings>
        <application path="/" applicationPool="example" preloadEnabled="true">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\home\site\wwwroot2" />
          <virtualDirectory path="/iisnodedebugger" physicalPath="C:\DWASFiles\Sites\example\Temp\iisnode" />
        </application>
      </site>
    </sites>
  </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

After restart the transform is successfull.

The problem: it has no effect. The customdomain.com is still served from "D:\home\site\wwwroot" and not "D:\home\site\wwwroot2".

After that i deleted only the bindigs without adding the new site, customdomain still working... After that i deleted the whole site (example), example.azurewebsites.net and customdomain.com still working.

Where am I mistaken? Isn't it possible to manipulate the sites section?

Answer (score 6):

May i ask why are you trying to make your life hard?

Why don't you deploy your 2nd application to a **new Web App**? You can share the same App Service Plan (same VM) if cost is the essence here.

Every Web App has its own custom domain settings which you can configure visually through the Portal:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

[image: Custom-Domain-UI]

Comment: I need to manage 3-4 domains of my client, and i don't really want to waste my time with the management of several web apps (different FTP's to log in, different backup etc.). Would be great to have everything at one place. One FTP with subdirectories for the different domains, one backup, one KUDU to use the console. Of course if there is really no other solution, than i will create separate web apps.

Comment: You cannot bind a domain to a specific filesystem path in App Service, if that's really your question.

Comment: Lets say that i need to change my client's company's logo. In the case of 4 web apps, i need to login to 4 different ftps. If i need to find a specific content, i need to use grep at 4 different places the KUDU console...

Comment: So for this specific task (sites section) the modification of applicationhost.config is not allowed via xdt?

Comment: Or simply update the graphics in 4 git repositories and hook up the Web Apps to pull from GitHub/Bitbucket/Whathaveyou.

Comment: Yes the key here is that although you will have multiple apps listed under "App Services", they can share the same "Hosting Plan"/"App Service Plan". And if you click an app, and then click the name of the app service plan/hosting plan, you can view all the Apps under that hosting plan as well.

Answer (score 0):

i did this in the webconfig and it seems to work:

```
**<rule name="REDIRECT To Site Within a Site" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}"pattern="^www\.SiteWithinSiteName\.com$" />
<add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/path/SiteWithinSiteRoot/" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="\path\SiteWithinSiteRoot\{R:0}" />
</rule>**
```